# how do i port my machine learning model from python to java web app?

Tags: python, java, tensorflow, scikit-learn, web-applications

so I've been developing some machine learning models using sklearn and tensorflow in python .
and I want to integrate it into a java web app.
so far I've been saving my models as .joblib
any idea how i can do it ?
I know this is a general question, but if someone can tell me if its possible , or do i have to retrain the models in java using java machine learning libraries a

some python code i used:

```
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='adam', alpha=Alpha,hidden_layer_sizes=(hid1,hid2), random_state=1,max_iter=10000)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_test_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
y_train_pred = clf.predict(x_train)
```

Comment: We can easily integrate CPython scripts in Java applications using the JavaCPP Presets for CPython, if that's your question: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/cpython

Comment: @SamuelAudet so i can load and run my python models inside java ?

Comment: Yes, we can do something like this in the case of, for example, TensorFlow: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/blob/master/tensorflow/samples/KerasMNIST.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @SamuelAudet said,i can integrate CPython scripts in Java applications using the JavaCPP Presets for CPython.
github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/cpython